# Unresolved dependencies npm run watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am attempting to import a module like this:

```
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
```

When I run "npm run watch", I get a bunch of these errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel-credentials.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in ...

ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in ...

ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in ...
```

It seems like I am unable to resolve some dependencies but I'm not sure how to fix this.

I ran:

```
~/learn-node $ node
> module.paths
```

to check that the folder containing @google-cloud/speech is in one of the paths that is searched, and it is.

```
** NEW warnings:

WARNING in ./node_modules/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate' in ...

WARNING in ./node_modules/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in ...

WARNING in ./node_modules/bytebuffer/dist/bytebuffer-node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'memcpy' in ...

WARNING in ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js 32:12-33
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Comment: Did you run npm install before do the require?

Comment: @JacoboTapia yes I did

Comment: Try to add `target: 'node'` to your module.exports object in webpack.config.js

Comment: @JacoboTapia that resolved the errors! Thanks! I am getting several warnings now (posted them in original question for formatting)